# Whether function declaration in Javascript of form `function fx () {}` a LHS or RHS lookup?

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine

I was reading the **Scopes and Closure** title of **You don't know JS** by Kyle Simpson, specifically this topic [Compiler Speak](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch1.md#compiler-speak). This section is about the kind of Lookups the engine uses. Now I understand what is LHS or RHS lookup to the extent given in this section.

My problem is the note saying that function declaration of the form `function fx(a) {..` is not a LHS lookup. There is an explanation given for the same, but I am unable the understand. Here is the whole note

> You might be tempted to conceptualize the function declaration function `foo(a) {...` as a normal variable declaration and assignment, such as `var foo` and `foo = function(a){...` . In so doing, it would be tempting to think of this function declaration as involving an LHS look-up. However, the subtle but important difference is that Compiler handles both the declaration and the value definition during code-generation, such that when Engine is executing code, there’s no processing necessary to “assign” a function value to `foo` . Thus, it’s not really appropriate to think of a function declaration as an LHS look-up assignment in the way we’re discussing them here.

Any kind of clarification would be helpful. Even on LHS and RHS lookups.

Answer (score 2):

The topic of "lookup" is one that has to do with **expression evaluation**.  A function declaration statement

```
function someName() {
  // code
}
```

is **not** an expression. It's a distinct statement type in the same way that `return` is a distinct statement type, and `while` and `if`.  No expression evaluation happens in a function declaration statement, other than the implicit instantiation of a new function object to be bound to the function name in the local scope.

The topic of LHS and RHS values (usually, in my experience, called *l-values* and *r-values* in the literature) is important, but it just has nothing to do with function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I shared the same question while reading. Pointy's answer above made the concept pretty clear, and I am just adding more explanation using the quote from a newer edition of the book:

"`function getStudentName(studentID) {`

A function declaration is a special case of a target reference. You can think of it sort of like var getStudentName = function(studentID), but that's not exactly accurate. An identifier getStudentName is declared (at compile time), but the = function(studentID) part is also handled at compilation; the association between getStudentName and the function is automatically set up at the beginning of the scope rather than waiting for an = assignment statement to be executed.

NOTE:
This automatic association of function and variable is referred to as "function hoisting", and is covered in detail in Chapter 5."

[Here is the link to the new edition on GithHub.](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch1.md)